# Can't load Bioconductor package genomewidesnp6cdf in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

New to R and Bioconductor, and I'm working off of code I got from someone else. I do:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("affy", version = "3.8")
BiocManager::install("oligo", version = "3.8")
BiocManager::install("pd.genomewidesnp.6", version = "3.8")

library(Biobase)
library(affy)
library(oligo)
library(pd.genomewidesnp.6)

data <- ReadAffy('myfile.CEL')
```

'myfile.CEL' is a 69 MB .CEL file from a particular project in [Synapse](https://www.synapse.org/#). Here's what `data` looks like after loaded into my environment:
[image]

Then if I do `eset <- rma(data)` I get the error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘rma’ for signature ‘"AffyBatch"’
```

And if I do `eset <- affy::rma(data)` I get:

```
Error in getCdfInfo(object) : 
  Could not obtain CDF environment, problems encountered:
Specified environment does not contain GenomeWideSNP_6
Library - package genomewidesnp6cdf not installed
Bioconductor - genomewidesnp6cdf not available
```

Google searches are not telling me what `genomewidesnp6cdf` is, whether it's the same as `pd.genomewidesnp.6`, and why I don't have it. Anyone know?

Comment: I got a different error message and one that made more sense given the lack of any arguments to ReadAffy: `data <- ReadAffy()
Error in AllButCelsForReadAffy(..., filenames = filenames, widget = widget,  : 
  No cel filennames specified and no cel files in specified directory:/home/david`. So ....The error from `rma(data)` was due to the name `data` being an R function.

Comment: Oh, the argument to ReadAffy() is the name of a 69 MB .CEL file in my working directory. I am able to load it in my environment it says `data` is loaded as a "Formal class AffyBatch". I tried changing the variable name `data` to `affydata` and got the same error.

Comment: @42- I've edited the question now to make this clearer.

Comment: The `oligo` version of `rma` (and oligo was loaded after affy, so its version is accessed) appears not to have a method for an AffyBatch object, so you definitely should be investigating the second error.

Comment: Perhaps you need `crlmm` and `genomewidesnp6Crlmm` but I think the BioStars help forum is probably a better place to be asking.

Comment: Tried loading both those packages, no luck. I've posted on biostars as well.